# Synchronization between two event handler running on same thread

Tags: c#, events, synchronization

Will appreciate your help in suggesting solution to below problem.

**Problem Description:**
In my application i receive *two events on same thread*, both the event handlers calls a method which does some task and has an Application.DoEvents() call in it.

When i receive Event1 it calls Event1_Handler, which call DoWork. In DoWork, we call start some work on other thread after that we call Application.DoEvents() and wait in for loop for .5 sec, which allow other pending events in thread pump get executed.
We get out of for loop either "Some Work" get completed or we wait for .5 Sec and then leave any way.

So DoWork from Event1_Handler is not yet completed and on the same time Event2 is received which calls Event2_Handler which interns call DoWork. This create undesired behavior.

These events always comes in order but can come after some ms apart.

```
using System;
using LoggerSpace;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
namespace SyncMech
{
    public delegate void MyDel();
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        event MyDel Event1;
        event MyDel Event2;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Some logger initialization stuff
            Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out));
            Trace.AutoFlush = true;
            Trace.Indent();
        }

        private void Event2_Handler()
        {
            Logger.LogThisLine(">>> Event2_Handler");
            DoWork();
            Logger.LogThisLine("<<< Event2_Handler");
        }

        private void Event1_Handler()
        {
            Logger.LogThisLine(">>> Event1_Handler");
            DoWork();
            Logger.LogThisLine("<<< Event1_Handler");
        }
        public void DoWork()
        {
            Logger.LogThisLine(">>> DoWork");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {

                // We get out of loop after 500 ms or when Heavy work is completed
                // completion of heavy work is notified by event hence Application.DoEvents is needed
                Logger.LogThisLine("Heavy work");
                Application.DoEvents();
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            Logger.LogThisLine("<<< DoWork");
        }
        public void RaiseEvents()
        {
            Event1.Invoke();

            // have difference of 20 ms between both events
            Thread.Sleep(20);

            Event2.Invoke();
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Created a simple UI app with only one button
            // Registered Event1 and Event2
            this.Event1 += () => this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)Event1_Handler);
            this.Event2 += () => this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)Event2_Handler);

            // Raise both the events from background thread
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(RaiseEvents)).Start();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
8/5/2017 7:45:43 PM :   >>> Event1_Handler  
8/5/2017 7:45:43 PM :   >>> DoWork  
8/5/2017 7:45:43 PM :   Heavy work  
8/5/2017 7:45:43 PM :   Heavy work  
8/5/2017 7:45:43 PM :   >>> Event2_Handler  
8/5/2017 7:45:43 PM :   >>> DoWork  
8/5/2017 7:45:43 PM :   Heavy work  
8/5/2017 7:45:44 PM :   Heavy work  
8/5/2017 7:45:44 PM :   Heavy work  
8/5/2017 7:45:44 PM :   Heavy work  
8/5/2017 7:45:44 PM :   Heavy work  
8/5/2017 7:45:44 PM :   <<< DoWork  
8/5/2017 7:45:44 PM :   <<< Event2_Handler  
8/5/2017 7:45:44 PM :   Heavy work  
8/5/2017 7:45:44 PM :   Heavy work  
8/5/2017 7:45:44 PM :   Heavy work  
8/5/2017 7:45:44 PM :   <<< DoWork  
8/5/2017 7:45:44 PM :   <<< Event1_Handler
```

This is a very old and large application, DoWork is called from multiple modules of this application and will have high impact if get changed.i know that work which need to be done in Event_Handler2 needs to be done after Event_Handler1. Putting a lock doesn't work as calls are on same thread.

**Question:** How do i insure that Event_Handler2 only get executed after processing of Event_Handler1 completes.Any other suggestion are also appreciated

Comment: This is basically a synchronization problem.But Using synchronization will become tedious for future debugging We generally use Wait Events.. I you can find out w from where these two events came you can use  easily synchronize.

Comment: Frankly, the above is _exactly_ why code that uses `Application.DoEvents()` is **fundamentally broken**. It's exactly this re-entrant scenario that comes up and which is almost never anticipated by the person who writes the code that's being called re-entrantly which is why one shouldn't be calling `DoEvents()` in the first place. The best fix above is to just remove the call to `Application.DoEvents()`. It will cause the UI thread to block while `DoWork()` is running, but that's better than the alternative. You can then take time to fix the code properly with `Task.Run()`.

Comment: Fixing the code without removing `Application.DoEvents()` will be much harder. It can be done -- e.g. keep a counter that `DoWork()` can loop on and increment it in each handler, calling `DoWork()` only if the counter was 0 to start with -- but there are lots of different ways to approach the problem, and none very good.

Comment: You're at the point where even trivial fixes require refactoring the code. I think Peter's advice is excellent. Or you can solve the problem by having event handler 2 call event handler 1 under certain conditions, fight bugs for days, and end up with with worse code for more work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll look for impact of removing Application.DoEvents(). One of the impact i found is that DoWork ask some other module to start a work and when that work get completed, SomeClass gets a event as notification of work completion which terminates for loop.
We want to wait for that event for 1.5 sec and if in that time the work is not completed we bail out of the loop anyways. I also updated the information in question

Comment: @zzxyz event1 and event2 are device events. Device guarantees that if event2 comes it will only come after event1 but its possible that event2 doesn't come at all. So calling Event_Handler1 from Event_Handler2 can create other problems

Comment: Things used to work fine...But then we got a device where timing between these two events is 20ms

Comment: @Peter as he is clearly states that DoWork is called by Event2 even the Event1 is not completed its work. And he is clearly mention he wants Event2  should execute after Event1 . My Solution a simple synchronization

Comment: @PeterDuniho Can you please elaborate on " calling DoWork() only if the counter was 0 to start with".

Comment: E.g. in your handlers `if (counter++ == 0) { SomeClass.DoWork(); }`. Then in the `DoWork()` method `while (counter-- > 0) { /* do your work */ }`. I would post it in an answer, but you really haven't provided enough information -- i.e. there is no [mcve] -- to be able to post an answer with a validated, confirmed-working solution.